# can I condense this?

Tags: python

```
invalid_characters = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"]
vowels = ["a","e","i","o","u"]

letter = str(input("Enter a letter: "))
while letter in invalid_characters:
    letter = input("You entered an invalid character. Please enter a letter: ")
if letter in vowels:
    print("The letter is a vowel")
else:
    print("The letter is a consonant")
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You can just make them plain strings instead of lists: `vowels = "aeiou"`

Comment: code tells user whether letter is a vowel or consonant. have i written too much though?

Comment: Also as a shortcut you can use `string.digits` which is a string of all digits from 0 to 9, instead of defining it yourself.

Comment: and use a `set` so `in` is faster

Comment: What do you want to "condense"?

Comment: So.. space, hyphen and backslash are consonants.. Wonder how you pronounce these (grin)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to make your code shorter, try this:

```
vowels = "aeiou"

letter = str(input("Enter a letter: "))
while letter.isdigit():
    letter = input("You entered an invalid character. Please enter a letter: ")
if letter in vowels:
    print("The letter is a vowel")
else:
    print("The letter is a consonant")
```

However, keep in mind that if you enter "$" or any other special symbol, it will say that it is a consonant.

If you want to make it a bit faster, as mentioned by Jean-François Fabre, yo could use a [set](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) to make `in` faster.

```py
vowels = set("aeiou")

letter = str(input("Enter a letter: "))
while letter.isdigit():
    letter = input("You entered an invalid character. Please enter a letter: ")
if letter in vowels:
    print("The letter is a vowel")
else:
    print("The letter is a consonant")
```

Comment: shouldn't the if/else be inside the loop?

Comment: @VisheshMangla: That loop is handling invalid input.

Comment: @VisheshMangla, seeing the original logic, I will say no.